# How to get current location in Android Programming

Tags: java, android, location

In my application I want get user **current location** and for this I write below codes.
But in **some devices** not show location and show me **null**!

In my application I want get user **current location** and for this I write below codes.
But in **some devices** not show location and show me **null**!

**My Java codes :**

```
void getLocation(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                    addressesORG = geocoderORG.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    cityNameORG = addressesORG.get(0).getLocality();
                    prefsUtils.setToShared(PrefsKeys.CITY_NAME.name(), cityName);
                    prefsUtils.setToShared(PrefsKeys.CITY_NAME_ORG.name(), cityNameORG);
                    showSimpleWeather();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("locationClickedLog", "Err : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
    } else {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.e("locationClickedLog", "" + location);
        if (location != null) {
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                addressesORG = geocoderORG.getFromLocation(latti, longi, 1);
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                cityNameORG = addressesORG.get(0).getLocality();
                prefsUtils.setToShared(PrefsKeys.CITY_NAME.name(), cityName);
                prefsUtils.setToShared(PrefsKeys.CITY_NAME_ORG.name(), cityNameORG);
                showSimpleWeather();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            getLocation(mContext);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Manifest permissions :**

```
<!-- Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

When log this : `Log.e("locationClickedLog", "" + location);` show me **null** into `logCat` !

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**Name of the network location provider.**

> This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower
>   and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network
>   lookup.

else condition try to use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

check here https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: check the above link how to get location using gps